# Unable to display element inside jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Kindly check the following url
[Click on It](http://busnow.in/new/Hotel/hotel_search.aspx?city=Agra&from=19/09/2013&to=26/09/2013&adl=3&cld=0)

Then click on the slect room button a accordion will open. i have some html codes inside that accordion but it is not showing even if the display is block. kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `opacity` from `.quickLook` css class. You have set `opacity:0` there, which makes everything inside that hidden

```
.quickLook{
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0; /* Remove this */
  }
```